# Prove continuity in the $p$-mean / Lebesgue Points

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

> **Lemma**: Let $p \in [1, \infty)$, $I := (a,b)$ a real interval and $u \in L^p(I)$ arbitrary.
>   Then we have
>   \begin{equation*}
>   \forall \varepsilon > 0 \
>   \exists \delta > 0:
>   | h | < \delta
>   \implies \left( \int_{a}^{b} | u(x + h) - u(x) |^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} < \varepsilon
>  \end{equation*}
>       where, outside of $I$ $u$ is trivially continued with 0.

**My Questions**

1. Why is the trivial continuation possible? Is it smooth? If $u$ had compact support on $I$, this is always possible, but that's not the case.
2. How would one prove this? [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91689/on-the-continuity-in-lp) is much more general, ($\mathbb{R}^d$ instead of $I$).
   And from the wikipedia proof of the [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem), which is wasn't able to follow, I assume I have to consider something like
   \begin{equation*}
   E_{\alpha}
   := \left\{x \in I: \limsup_{\substack{x \in I \\ b \searrow a}} \frac{1}{b - a} \left| \int_{a}^{b} u(y) dy - u(x)\right| > 2 \alpha \right\}
    \end{equation*}
   and show it has measure 0 for all $\alpha > 0$ and use that continuous compactly support functions are dense.

We have already shown a similar result way earlier, but since $u$ need not be uniformly continuous, I don't know how to recycle this proof for the proof of the lemma above.

> **Theorem**
>   Let $X$ be a real Banach space and $u \in \mathcal{C}([a,b]; X)$ a function.
>   Then we have
>
> 1. $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{t}^{t + h} u(s) ds = u(t)$ for all $t \in [a,b]$.
> 2. $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{t}^{t + h} \| u(s) - u(t) \| ds = 0$ for all $t \in [a,b]$.
> 3. $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \int_{a}^{b} \| u(t + h) - u(t) \| dt = 0$, where $u$ is trivially continued with 0.

**Proof**
1. follows from 2:
\begin{align*}
\left\| \frac{1}{h} \int_{t}^{t + h} u(s) ds - u(t) \right\|_{X}
& = \left\| \frac{1}{h} \int_{t}^{t + h} u(s) ds - \int_{t}^{t + h} u(t) ds \right\|_{X} \\
& \le \frac{1}{| h |} \int_{\min(t, t +h)}^{\max(t, t + h)} \| u(s) - u(t) \|_X ds \xrightarrow{2.} 0.
\end{align*}

2. Because $u$ is continuous for an arbitrary $t \in [a,b]$, we have
   $$
   \forall \varepsilon > 0  \ \exists \delta > 0:
   \| u(t) - u(s) \| < \varepsilon \
   \forall s \in [a,b] \text{ with } | s - t | \le \delta.
   $$
   Choose $|h| < \delta$.
   We conclude
   $$
   \frac{1}{h} \int_{t}^{t + h} \underbrace{\| u(s) - u(t) \|}_{< \varepsilon} ds
   < \varepsilon.
   $$
3. $u$ is uniformly continuous:
   $$
   \forall \tilde{\varepsilon} > 0
   \exists \tilde{\delta} > 0:
   \| u(t) - u(s) \| \le \tilde{\varepsilon} \
   \forall s,t \in [a,b]  \text{ with } | s - t | \le \delta.
   $$
   For $|h| < \tilde{\delta}$ (and w.l.og. $h > 0$) we have
   \begin{align*}
   \int_{a}^{b} \| u(t + h) - u(t) \| dt
   &= \int_{a}^{b - h} \| u(t + h) - u(t) \| dt + \int_{b - h}^{b} \| 0 - u(t) \| dt \\
   & \le \tilde{\varepsilon} (b - a) + \|u \|_{\infty} \cdot h.
   \end{align*}

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and set $|h| < \min\left\{ \frac{\varepsilon}{2 \| u \|_{\infty}}, \tilde{\delta} \right\}$ (w.l.og. $u \not\equiv 0$) and choose $\tilde{\delta}$ with respect to $\tilde{\varepsilon} := \frac{\varepsilon}{2(b - a)}$. $\square$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $h\in\mathbb R$ let $T_h : L^p(\mathbb R)\to L^p(\mathbb R)$ be defined by $T_hu(x) = u(x+h)$. Note that $\|T_hu\|_p = \|u\|_p$ for all $u\in L^p(\mathbb R)$.

Now, let $u\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ be fixed and let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then we find $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that $\|u-\phi\|_p < \epsilon/3$. Hence,
$$
\|T_hu - u\|_p\,\le\,\|T_h(u-\phi)\|_p + \|T_h\phi - \phi\|_p + \|\phi-u\|_p < \frac 23\epsilon + \|T_h\phi - \phi\|_p.
$$
Now, by what you have already shown for uniformly continuous $u$ we find $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
\|T_h\phi - \phi\|_p = \left(\int|\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)|^p\,dx\right)^{1/p} < \frac\epsilon 3
$$
for $|h| < \delta$. Thus, for these $|h|<\delta$ we have $\|T_hu - u\|_p < \epsilon$.

Comment: Concerning your first question: We have $u\in L^p$. This can be terribly non-smooth. Of course, you can extend it by zero to $\mathbb R$. And I don't understand your very last question. The function $\phi$ is uniformly continuous and you have the statement already for uniformly continuous functions.